# Google Sheets auto-format the highest value in a row of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I have a set of data like so:

```
  A|B|C|D
1 9|3|5|4
2 7|6|6|6
3 3|6|2|7
4 6|9|4|7
```

And I would like to auto-format the highest value in each row. So, for instance in row 1, A1 would get the auto-format, row 2: A2, row 3: D3, row 4: B4. I have been playing with auto format using `=percentrank()`, but cannot get the hang of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideal case for Conditional Formatting (Format - Conditional formatting....), having selected A1:D4:

Choose **Custom formula is** (only available in new Google Sheets),
Enter there:

```
=A1=max($A1:$D1)
```

Select your formatting, <kbd>Save rules</kbd>.